# Is this Language decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

As the title says;
is this language decidable and how do you prove it?

$$L =\{\langle M\rangle \mid M \text{ is a Turing Machine and there is an input that } M \text{ halts on} \} $$

Comment: Turing machines are not decidable (or undecidable). *Languages* are decidable.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: the title doesn't ask `Is this Turing machine decidable?`, but  `Is this Turing-Machine decidable?`, and the pixel raster shows a language.)

Comment: thanks for noting. I'm a bit new to these definitions.

Comment: It's not decidable. You could use [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem) to prove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your language is not decidable. To show that it suffices to notice that the existence of a Turing machine $T$ that decided $L$ implies the existence of a Turing machine that solves the halting problem.

Indeed, given any Turing machine $M$ with input $x$ you can construct a Turing machine $M'$ that ignores its input, writes $x$ on the tape, and then simulates $M$. Clearly $M'$ halts (regardless of its input) if and only if $M$ halts on input $x$. We can decide whether $M'$ halts by checking whether $M' \in L$ using $T$ with input $M'$.